# align span to top of th and input to bottom of same th

Tags: html, css

I'm using a library that generates tables with headers like this

```
<th>
<span class="xxx">header title</span>
<span class="sort_icon"/>
<input text (optional, depending on column definition for filtering) class="yyy">
</th>
```

what I would like to do is with pure css make the header title and sort icon align to top of the th element, and input element if present to the bottom of th element.

My problem is that vertical-align can be set only to th element and thus making both spans and input to go top or bottom, but I cannot figure out a way to align differenty spans and input

Answer (score 0):

Usually in this type of situation it's easier to use absolute positioning:

```
<style type="text/css">
.th
{
position:relative;
}

.xxx
{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
}


.yyy
{
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
}
</style>
```

The only drawback is you have to make sure the height of the th is enough to accomodate the sort icon. That's pretty easy - just set a height and any necessary margin/padding on it, or on the th.

Answer (score 0):

Fixid position is an option, but it is going to be hard to keep the input box on the bottom since you don't know how much content will be in the header. It might go on 2 lines and others on 1.

You might try something in like in the example below. The span tags aren't block elements so you cannot move the so easely. Therefor, use display:block and then work with margins and padding.

PS.: better use css file... inline styles are just for example

```html
<table>
<tbody><tr>
<th style="
    max-height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align: top;
">
<span class="xxx" style="
    display: block;
">header title</span>
<span class="sort_icon" style="
    display: block;
    margin-top: 200;
">
<input text="" (optional,="" depending="" on="" column="" definition="" for="" filtering)="" class="yyy">
</span></th>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
```